# Do I need to log in to an Ubuntu system as root to make a complete backup?

Tags: backup, root, users

This is a re-edit, because no one seems to want to answer the actual question.

To simplify: Will a non-root backup save everything? Do I have to log in as root to copy sbin, home, etc to a backup disk?

Thanks for all the answers on logging in as root, but that wasn't the problem.

Comment: "but I can't seem to log in as "root" to do this." Use your admin account and `sudo`. Using a "root" on Linux is a small security risk and does not correctly log usage of the person doing something on your system. With `sudo` all account actions are registered to your admin account,

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Comment: Thanks, but, again, it doesn't address the problem:  Can I back up everything useful just as an ordinary user?  Do I have to log in as admin or root?

Comment: What do you mean by "everything"? What do you mean by "backup"?

Comment: 1. A **complete backup can be achieved by cloning the whole drive**. You do that with [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org), booted from a CD disk or USB pendrive, and either create a cloned copy on a third drive of at least the same size as the original one, or better: create a Clonezilla image, which is a directory containing several files where the big ones are compressed; 2. You can run [backup systems](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem), that **backup all your personal files more or less automatically** with or without root permissions (like suggested by @Panther).

Comment: @sudodus Make that a proper answer instead of a comment

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, Done :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Complete backup - cloning the whole drive

- A complete backup can be achieved by cloning the whole drive. You do that with [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), booted from a CD disk or USB pendrive.

  - either create a cloned copy on a third drive of at least the same size as the original one,
- or better: create a Clonezilla image, which is a directory containing several files where the big ones are compressed.

### Backup all your personal files

- You can run backup systems, that backup all your personal files more or less automatically with or without root permissions (like suggested by @Panther). See this link,

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem)

It is possible to

- configure the backup system to backup the directories and files, that you think are most important to backup,
- you can select incremental backup
- you can select compression or no compression
- you can configure when (and how often) you want to run your backup system.

depending on the backup tool that you select.